# Dart Language: how to get an image from another element?

Tags: css, web-applications, dart

I have two table rows at an HTML file: the first one is empty and the other one has a background image. I would like to know if there's any way to get that background image and transfer it to the first row when it gets clicked.

(Right now I'm setting the background image at the CSS code, but I think that I'll have to move it to the HTML in order for it to work. Or maybe not?)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you have tried so far..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

index.html

```dart
<head>
  <style>
    div {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    #id1 {
      background-image: url('action-icons.png');
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='id1'>xxx</div>
  <div id='id2'>yyy</div>
</body>
```

index.dart

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main () {
  querySelector('#id2').onClick.listen((e) {
    var div1 = querySelector('#id1');
    var div2 = querySelector('#id2');
    div2.style.backgroundImage = div1.getComputedStyle().backgroundImage;
    div1.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
  });
}
```